# Docker compose cant find file inside docker build context

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**Error**

```
ERROR [4/5] RUN cat ./test.txt                                                                                                                                                                    
0.2s
------
> [4/5] RUN cat ./test.txt:
#0 0.225 cat: ./test.txt: No such file or directory
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cat ./test.txt" did not complete successfully:  
exit code: 1
```

**Solutions tried**

1. change file permission to 777
2. double check file location if its indeed inside the context build dir
3. checked ownership (looks fine)
4. Checked if test.txt is a hidden file
5. checked if .dockerignore is ignoring the file
6. run the build with --no-cache. No difference

**docker compose file**

```
fortune_teller_worker:
  build:
    context: /home/lds/apps/fortuneteller/Docker/Cron  
    dockerfile: DockerfileCron             
  restart: always
  container_name: ft_worker
  volumes:
    - /home/lds/apps/fortuneteller:/app
  working_dir: /app
  networks:
    - my_app_net
  command: bash -c "service cron start && pip install -r requirements.txt && tail -f /dev/null"
```

**docker file**

Obviously, I havent run the Dockerfile with <<, I added them just to explain what I have tried

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y cron vim && \
    pip install --upgrade pip


RUN cat ./test.txt << doesnt work with ./
RUN cat test.txt << doesnt work
RUN cat /test.txt << doesnt work with /

WORKDIR /app <<< tried this before and after the RUN cat.. no difference

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

**directory tree**

```
builder/
└── docker-compose.yml

app/
└── Docker/
    └── Cron/
        ├── DockerfileCron
        └── test.txt
```

**Summary**

I cant find a way to get this working. What else could I try to debug this issue?

In case you are wondering why I'm running `RUN cat test.txt` its only to test if i can actually indeed find a file inside the docker build context.

Comment: You must copy your app (including `test.txt`) to the Docker image.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that? add the whole app to the build context?

Comment: You need a line like `COPY test.txt ./` (probably after the `WORKDIR` setting and before the `RUN` line).  Nothing exists in your image unless it comes from the base image, a `RUN` line creates it, or you `COPY` it in.

Comment: That worked thanks. I feel stupid now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solutions have been shared in the comments.

When building with Docker Compose, it doesn't establish volume connections during the build stage. Therefore, you need to copy the files you use during the build stage into the container

You can edit the **Dockerfile** as shown below to make it work

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y cron vim && \
    pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./test.txt /app/
RUN cat test.txt

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```